# Laravel Migration and seeder without removing previous data

Tags: laravel, database-migration, laravel-10

I have a database with multiple tables.
i want to update user table and seeders only without doing **php artisan migration:fresh -seed** .
database is in production so i cant rollback all the tables except users table

I am trying to update user and seeders.

Comment: What is the issue? How do you want to update? And what do you want to update? You need to add a lot of details

Comment: php artisan db:seed --class=UserSeeder

Comment: I have user table earlier but the issue is that now i want to add some new fields in users table. i have use spatie package for roles and permission.
i used seeder for admin data to seed in user table and roles table.

Comment: Then create a new seeder `NewUserSeeder` where you will add the users in this seeder. after that, run `php artisan db:seed --class=NewUserSeeder`

Comment: If you want to delete all users then reseed, you can change the method to delete the users, then use the same artisan command

Comment: but wait what columns do you want to add to the user table if you want to use spatie permissions ?

Comment: i added f_name ,l_name,business,number in table
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('f_name');
            $table->string('l_name');
            $table->string('number')->nullable();
            $table->string('business');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: okay don't add this to user migrations the extra fields I am talking about, create a migration will add these columns to the users table and make them nullable, then migrate it and then run the command I provided on the top

Comment: spatie permissions has nothing to do with the users table

Comment: Ok thank you so much :)